# Need to create a script that creates directory structure from CSV

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell, csv

Beginner programmer here.

I need to create a script that takes a csv file (or multiple csv files) all in the same format. The script needs to read the csv row by row, and use certain columns to extract info to make a directory structure. Then the raw data file (whose location is in a column in the csv) needs to be copied over to the new directory structure that has been created.

I created a script in Python to create the directory structure in my user directory. But now I am working with a linux server so I was wondering if I should do anything differently. Also my script does not copy the raw data file from it's location into the new directory structure.

Do I need to code this all in Bash or leave it in Python?

The CSV looks basically like this:

```
Raw Data File Name-----File Location-----(ParentFolderInfo)-----(SubFolderInfo)-----(ChildFolderInfo)-----...
```

Comment: have you actually tried it? do you actually have a problem? There are definitely cross platform incompatibilities, but there shouldn't be too much to change.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how the script handles filenames. If you've been doing simple string manipulation with Windows-style paths you will probably have a compatibility problem, but using the [os.path module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html) to construct your filepaths should take care of any problems.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like:

```
 awk -F "-----" '{ print "mv "$2" "$3"/"$4"/"$5"/"$6 }' filename | sh
```

With awk, set the delimiter to "-----" and then build a move command that can then be printed and then executed by piping through to sh.